# Mudar o estado de um componente checkbox no banco usando AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

muito boa noite a todos!

Bem, tenho uma tabela na qual existe um componente de checkbox. Esse componente tem a tarefa de ativar e desativar um destino no meu website. A figura abaixo mostra uma linha da tabela com o tal elemento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o codigo html, ele faz a verificação apenas se está vindo true ou false do banco para renderizar na tela:

```
<c:forEach items="${destination}" var="d">
   <tr>
      <td>${d.dtName}</td>
      <td>${d.categories.ctName}</td>
      <td>
         <div class="make-switch" data-on="primary" data-off="info">
            <c:choose>
               <c:when test="${d.dtAppearWebsite}">
                  <input type="checkbox" checked>
               </c:when>
               <c:otherwise>
                  <input type="checkbox">
               </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Bem, minha pergunta é como eu poderia mudar o estado do meu componente via AJAX e refletir no banco de dados. A duvida maior é como vou pegar tal componente e fazer a mudança de forma assíncrona.

Alguém ai já fez algo parecido e pode me dar uma força?

Obrigado pela atenção de todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer a alteração no banco, você precisa ter uma action que faz isso. Vamos considerar que há 2 actions, a `ativarDestino` e a `desativarDestino`. Quando o checkbox estiver selecionado vamos chamar a ativar, do contrário chamamos a outra.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // usando id para identificar o checkbox
    $('#myCheckbox').click(function() {
        var action = $(this).is(':checked') ? 'ativarDestino' : 'desativarDestino';

        // uma vez determinada a action, é só usar o get do jQuery
        $.get(action, function(data) {
            // faz alguma coisa com o retorno, manda msg de sucesso, algo assim
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            // se der problema cai aqui. Você pode exibir o erro e desfazer a checagem do checkbox
        });
    });
});
```

Você pode ver a documentação do jQuery.get aqui: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Oi Juliano tudo joia? Obrigado pela ajuda, mas quando se trata do componente HTML como eu posso fazer? Pois atualmente eu tenho um "when" que verifica isso para mim. Mas não sei como posso fazer utilizando o metodo JS que você me passou. Poderia me ajudar? Um abraço!